# Webservice Call issue in Oracle Plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Below is part of my plsql code for webservice call, if am hardcoding lv_activity_token code is working fine,same is not working when am getting it from below expression

```
iv_offset_cnt:=0;
lv_activity_token:= substr(iv_activity_token,instr(iv_activity_token,'/',2)+1);--with this code is not working
--iv_activity_token is coming from oracle table which i stored in table from different web service response
-- lv_activity_token:='2562432'; hardcoding the same value which is coming from above expression,with this code is working
lv_ws_url:='https://secure.p03.eloqua.com:443/api/bulk/2.0/syncs/';
lv_ws_url1:='/data?limit=200&offset=';
gv_ws_url := lv_ws_url || lv_activity_token || lv_ws_url1 || iv_offset_cnt;
--at the end gv_ws_url value is:
--https://secure.p03.eloqua.com:443/api/bulk/2.0/syncs/2562432/data?limit=200&offset=0
```

**additional detials:**

gv_ws_url --passing this to get the response.

Please let me know if you need any other details.

(i was doubting with data which is storing in table(may be character set issue))

thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `lv_activity_toke` look like if you `dbms_output.put_line` it?

Comment: output of lv_activity_token is 2562432, if am hard coding the same value, code is working fine.

Comment: Did you check for non-printable characters (e.g. linebreaks) ?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt actual response is '{"syncedInstanceUri":"/activities/exports/2685413","status":"pending","createdAt":"2019-01-09T15:59:27.3753252Z","createdBy":"test.userb","uri":"/syncs/2562432"}' from this using my custom function am getting 2562432 and storing in lv_activity_token, can you tell me still i need to check non-printable values,if yes,can you tell how can i do it? thanks

Comment: lv_activity_token:=regexp_replace(lv_activity_token,'[^'||chr(1)||'-'||chr(127)||']','');  lv_activity_token:=regexp_replace(lv_activity_token,'['||chr(127)||'-'||chr(225)||']','');    
 i tried this code as well,still it is not working